# Index of last vowel in a string

Tags: javascript, indexing

I've been sent a project in which I'm to index the last occurrence of a vowel within a string. I've unfortunately been receiving inconsistent results, ranging from `-1` which it naturally wouldn't be, to `84`, or `50`.
I've attempted running this as a loop, but unfortunately I'm not quite able to grasp any alternate way to solve this nor am I able to fully understand why my results are inconsistent.

I've attempted the following:

```
let myString = 'jrfndklhgfndjkjlkgperfijfhdknsadcvjhiiohjfkledsopiuhgtyujwsdxcvhgfdjhiopiwquhejkdsoiufghedjwsh'
let substr =  ('a','e','i','o','u');
const lastVowel = myString.lastIndexOf(substr);

console.log(lastVowel);
```

I'm not necessarily asking for any answers, an explanation, or even hinting at a solution would be appreciated. If any any were to be pasted, however, I'd be happy tinkering with it to further comprehension. I'm not really going to turn any form of help away.

Comment: `let substr =  ('a','e','i','o','u');` will just be `'u'`. You're probably looking for an array, which uses square brackets syntax `[ ]`

Comment: `('a','e','i','o','u')` isn't an array, it will actually evaluate to `'u'`. You need to use square brackets: `['a','e','i','o','u']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no `findLastIndex()` method [yet](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-find-from-last), what you can do, is reverse your array, get the first index of a vowel and subtract that from the string's (length-1) to get your initial position:

```js
let myString = 'jrfndklhgfndjkjlkgperfijfhdknsadcvjhiiohjfkledsopiuhgtyujwsdxcvhgfdjhiopiwquhejkdsoiufghedjwsh'
let vowels =  ['a','e','i','o','u'];

let arr = myString.split("").reverse(); // split string into array, and reverse it
let indexOfLastVowelInReverse = arr.findIndex(e => vowels.includes(e))

if(indexOfLastVowelInReverse != -1) { // if the index is -1 there is no vowel in the string
  let index = myString.length-1-indexOfLastVowelInReverse
  console.log(`Last vowel found at index ${index}: ${myString[index]}`)
}
```

Comment: Brilliant - Thank you!
It's quite frustrating where I am currently, I'm able to read back code and understand it however in the situation I'm still struggling at the right questions to be asking.

Thank you for the answer, comments and above all else - Your time :)

Comment: @lariz no worries, everyone struggles finding the right way to ask from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go about this, I have chosen a fairly lazy and inefficient way.  A better way would be to use a single loop and check for each vowel.  This way calculates the last position of each of the vowels and takes the greatest.

```js
let myString = 'jrfndklhgfndjkjlkgperfijfhdknsadcvjhiiohjfkledsopiuhgtyujwsdxcvhgfdjhiopiwquhejkdsoiufghedjwsh';
let substr =  ['a','e','i','o','u'];

// calculate lastIndex for each vowel separately, then take the greatest
const lastVowel = Math.max.apply(null, substr.map(letter => myString.lastIndexOf(letter)));

console.log(lastVowel, myString[lastVowel]);
```

Comment: Thank you man, it definitely works.
It's a bit beyond my scope right now, but you've pointed me in the direction of further learning.

Fully appreciate a lot of coding is about knowing the right questions to be asking, which I'm still adapting to. This helps in more way than one, so thank you! :)

Answer (score -1):

can you turn substr into an array and iterate through it.

['a','e','i','o','u'] instead of ('a','e','i','o','u').

"('a','e','i','o','u')" is not found.  Search each one and find the greatest number.

Math.max(...substr.map( vowel => myString.lastIndexOf(vowel)))